# issue with my fetch request, request body becomes null

Tags: express, post, fetch, postman, httprequest

I created a simple Node & Express server to catch a **POST request** and to send the **request body as a response**. And it is perfectly working on postman below is a screenshot of working request on the postman,

[So this is the response i get in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4HOd.jpg)

And here is my **backend** code.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at port 3000'))

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/api/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('A post request have recieved')
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send('This is the body of that POST request' + JSON.stringify(req.body))
})
```

But when I try to create that same POST request using fetch with an HTML button, the received request body (which I have sent with fetch) becomes null.

Here is the **HTML**,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>fetcher</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input value="click" id="btn" type="button" onclick="buttonFunc()" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the **javascript** for that,

```
function buttonFunc() {
  const data = {
    name: 'john',
  }
  console.log('clicked')

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  }

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/', options)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.body)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error)
    })
}
```

I can't find any mistakes in my code. Can anyone please help me to figure it out ?

I'll also attach a screenshot from my browser.

[Browser response with null as body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TVYY.jpg)

And here are some screenshots for a total response.

[console.log(response)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P17SZ.jpg)

[response in network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWTAP.jpg)

Comment: What do you get if you just write `console.log(response)` ?

Comment: Hey, can you check the question again I have attached 2 more screenshots. one with the full response and another showing the response in the network tab.

Comment: I have added an answer, please check

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the response to json

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to send response like below:

```
app.post('/api/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('A post request have recieved')
  console.log(req.body)

  var resData = {
        status: 1,
        message: "Success",
        data: req.body
  };
  return res.status(200).json(resData);
})
```